# jQuery bind function to multiple events

Tags: jquery, bind

I have a jQuery function that adds a new menu area if the page is scrolled down past X pixels. All good. If the page is refreshed past the pixel value, the function is not triggered. I have tried adding (binding) an extra event to the function handler, but no joy. I have the desired effect working, but have resorted to extra code:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
var num = 130; //number of pixels before modifying styles

console.log($(window).scrollTop());

// i have tried load, ready. what can I do???
$(window).bind('load scroll', function() 
{
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) 
    {
        $('.now_page').addClass('fixed');
        $('.now_page_res').fadeOut(0);
        $('.now_page_overlay').fadeIn(500).css("display","block").css("visibility","visible");          
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('.now_page').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.now_page_overlay').fadeOut(100).css("display","none").css("visibility","hidden");
        $('.now_page_res').fadeIn(500);
        //$('#cart_container').fadeIn(500);
    }
});

// EXTRA CODE HERE.... FFS there must be a way to bind the function above to page load...
{
if ($(window).scrollTop() > num)                        
    $('.now_page').addClass('fixed');
    $('.now_page_res').fadeOut(100);
    $('.now_page_overlay').fadeIn(500).css("display","block").css("visibility","visible");          
}
});
```

Any sugestions on what I can do to get this to work without the extra code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already inside window.onload, so just trigger the scroll event :

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    var num = 130;

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
            $('.now_page').addClass('fixed');
            $('.now_page_res').fadeOut(0);
            $('.now_page_overlay').fadeIn(500).css("display", "block").css("visibility", "visible");
        } else {
            $('.now_page').removeClass('fixed');
            $('.now_page_overlay').fadeOut(100).css("display", "none").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $('.now_page_res').fadeIn(500);
        }
    }).trigger('scroll'); // triggers the above function on window.onload
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! I had to change the bind to on('scroll' as suggested. Much better!

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the scroll event on the window manually:

```
$(function () {
    var num = 130,
        $nowPage = $('.now_page'),
        $nowPageOverlay = $('.now_page_overlay'),
        $nowPageRes = $('.now_page_res');

    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
            $nowPage.addClass('fixed');
            $nowPageRes.fadeOut(0);
            $nowPageOverlay.fadeIn(500).css("display", "block").css("visibility", "visible");
        } else {
            $nowPage.removeClass('fixed');
            $nowPageOverlay.fadeOut(100).css("display", "none").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $nowPageRes.fadeIn(500);
        }
    });

    $(window).trigger('scroll');
});
```